Google Sheets: merge two columns in order and loop them
I'm not sure how to best describe this, but let's say I have the following two columns:



Column 1
Column 2




A
X


B
Y


C
Z


D




I'm hoping to write a google sheets formula to make a continuous list like this, where the two columns are combined, and then repeat the lists infinitely (drag down):



Column 3




A


X


B


Y


C


Z


D


X (column 2 starts repeating here)


A (column 1 starts repeating here)


Y


B


Z


C


X (column 2 starts repeating here)


D


Y


A (column 1 starts repeating here)


...



I've tried various arraylist formulas, but nothing seems to get me what I need.

loop them how many times?

In theory infinitely - just drag down the box for however many is needed

try:
=LET(r, ROWS(A:A), s, SEQUENCE(r), ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(TOCOL(
 {ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(REDUCE(, s, LAMBDA(a, b, {TOCOL(A2:A, 1); a})), r, 1), 
  ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(REDUCE(, s, LAMBDA(a, b, {TOCOL(B2:B, 1); a})), r, 1)}, 1, ), r-ROW()+1, 1))


to cut it in the middle, change r-ROW()+1 to 15 for example


Here's one approach. For demo purposes here I've set the loop number to 5. Change the rept number as you need in reality
=let(rept,5, Λ,tocol(A:A,1), Ξ,tocol(B:B,1), Σ,tocol(map(Λ,lambda(x,wraprows(x,rept,x))),,1),
 tocol(hstack(Σ,array_constrain(tocol(map(Ξ,lambda(x,wraprows(x,roundup(rows(Σ)/rows(Ξ)),x))),,1),rows(Σ),1))))


